# Firedac Passing Column name as Parameter

Tags: delphi, firedac

In Delphi Firedac I have a very long query. I would like to reuse it just changing the name of a column via parameter like this

```
select f1, f2
from t1
where id = :par1
and :colimn_name = :value_name
```

Passing the :column_name parameter the reult query is like this:

```
select f1, f2
from t1
where id = 123
and 'department_name' = 'production'
```

with 2 '' wrapping the column name.

How can I avoid this, is there a specific way in FireDAC?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's what FireDAC offers macros for: [Substitution Variables](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Preprocessing_Command_Text_(FireDAC)#Substitution_Variables)

```
select f1, f2
from t1
where id = :par1
and &column_name = :value_name
```

Setting the actual columns goes this way:

```
myQuery.MacroByName('column_name').AsRaw := 'department_name';
```

**Edit:** As the column name happens to be a DB *identifier*, using `AsIdentifier` instead of `AsRaw` should work as well. That could even be necessary when the column name can be some reserved word in the DB and has to be quoted somehow.

Comment: I do love FireDAC and Delphi